# Giving an activity that observes a viewModel, can that activity assign value directlty to viewModel livedata

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata

Is it a good practice to call this from activity:

`viewModel.somedata = "some value"`

Knowing that the activity is already observing the viewModel and somedata is a livedata

Answer (score 0):

To keep with MVVM guidelines, it's better for the ViewModel to take care of that.  The view will be updated after the model is updated.

**Example in Kotlin:**

With this example model, and extension function to update the value:

```
data class MyModel(
        val somedata: String,
        val otherdata: String
)


fun MyModel.toStateWithNewSomedata(newSomedata: String): MyModel =
        this.copy(
                somedata = newSomedata
        )
```

And this LiveData definition in the ViewModel:

```
var myLiveData = MutableLiveData<MyModel>()
```

You then have this method defined in the ViewModel, that you can call from the view to update the value:

```
fun updateSomedata(newVal: String) {
    myLiveData.value?.let { model ->
        val updatedModel = model.toStateWithNewSomedata(newVal)
        myLiveData.postValue(updatedModel)
    }
}
```

Then you can still observe as normally in the View:

```
    viewModel.myLiveData.observe(this, Observer { updatedModel ->
        //update view with updated model
        val newSomedata = updatedModel.somedata

    })
```

If you call the `updateSomedata()` method, it will update the model, which will update the view.